# Removing specific keys from sub documents

Tags: php, mongodb

My mongodb collection structure is somewhat like this

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('')",
    "user_id": 52,
    "messages": [
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 1",
        "flag": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 2"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 3"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 4",
        "flag": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 5",
        "flag": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 6"
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to remove the key `flag` from each Object of messages array

I have found solution by using `$`, but it only removes `flag` from the first element.

Is there any way I can remove all of the `flag` with just one query ?

My expected end result is

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('')",
    "user_id": 52,
    "messages": [
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 1"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 2"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 3"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 4"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 5"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId('')",
        "message": "Hello world 6"
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with the new positional operator [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]) (since v 3.6)

```
db.collection.update( {}, {$unset: {"messages.$[].flag":""}} )
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response but the above query is not working.
Nothing happens after executing this query.

Comment: Which MongoDB version you use ? I've tested on 3.6.0 and it removed all flag properties.

Comment: I'm using the latest, 3.6.1

Comment: Did you try without any filtering conditions - just as I edited my answer ?

Comment: That doesn't solve the purpose. I want to update only for one user.

Comment: The output is as follows

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`